# Выборка существующих и отсутствующих значений из другой таблицы (SQL)

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток всем.

Есть table_product

```
id_product; name
1; Обувь
2; Шапки
3; Брюки
4; Куртки
5; Рубашки
```

есть table_option

```
id_option; product_id; color
1; 3; синий
2; 4; зеленый
5; 1; красный
```

Необходимый ответ

```
id_product; name; color
1; Обувь1; красный
2; Шапки; NULL
3; Брюки; синий
4; Куртки; зеленый
5; Рубашки; NULL
```

то есть в ответе присутствуют все строки из table_product,  столбец  color - в нем или соответствующее значение или NULL, если нет соответствующей записи.

У меня вариант вложенного SELECT  работает,  но наверное есть более правильное решение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LEFT OUTER JOIN` (`LEFT JOIN`) использовали?
Как-то так:

```
SELECT p.id_product, p.name, o.color
FROM table_product p LEFT JOIN table_option o
ON p.id_product = o.product_id;
```

Пример: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c2838b/6/0